# Custom adapter doesn't show the data

Tags: java, android, adapter

I am trying to create a custom adapter and i pass it a JSONArray, but it does not show anything.
the adapter is this:

```
public class MasonryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MasonryAdapter.MasonryView> {

    int[] imgList = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
            R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};
    JSONArray arrayofresults;
    private Context context;

    public MasonryAdapter(Context context, String results) throws JSONException {
        this.context = context;
        arrayofresults = new JSONArray(results);
        Toast.makeText(context, "length" + arrayofresults.length(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public MasonryView onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View layoutView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
        MasonryView masonryView = new MasonryView(layoutView);
        return masonryView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MasonryView holder, int position) {
        try {
            JSONObject tmpObj = arrayofresults.getJSONObject(position);
            holder.imageView.setImageResource(imgList[position]);
            Toast.makeText(context, "username" + tmpObj.getString("username"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            holder.textView.setText(tmpObj.getString("username"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayofresults.length();
    }

    class MasonryView extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        public MasonryView(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_name);
        }
    }
}
```

and i set it like this:
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
but still doesn't show anything. I am trying to show it in a fragment.
Here is the code for the fragment:

```
public class UserListFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView usernameView;
    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    Context context;
    MasonryAdapter adapter;
    private View view;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home_fragment, container, false);
        try {
            init();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return view;
    }

    private void init() throws JSONException {
        context = this.getActivity();
        usernameView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.user);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.masonry_grid);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        new LoginRunner().execute("http://velvet.kavalinis.eu/getUsers.php");
    }

    public void showResult(String serverResponse) throws JSONException {
        if (serverResponse == null || serverResponse.isEmpty()) {
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            TextView title = new TextView(context);
            title.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.login_fail_title));
            title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);   // Set Position
            title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            title.setTextSize(20);
            alertDialog.setCustomTitle(title);
            TextView msg = new TextView(context);
            msg.setText(context.getResources().getString(R.string.login_fail));
            msg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
            msg.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            alertDialog.setView(msg);
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, context.getResources().getString(R.string.try_again_btn), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    alertDialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, context.getResources().getString(R.string.register_btn), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });

            new Dialog(context.getApplicationContext());
            alertDialog.show();
        } else {
            adapter = new MasonryAdapter(this.getActivity(), serverResponse);
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            SpacesItemDecoration decoration = new SpacesItemDecoration(16);
            mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(decoration);
        }
    }

    private class LoginRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        //private String resp;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String responseStr = null;
            try {
                // HttpClient
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                // post header
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://velvet.gr);
                // add your data
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test"));
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                // execute HTTP post request
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    responseStr = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity).trim();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return responseStr;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            try {
                if (progressDialog != null) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
                showResult(result);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Loading...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

}

The JSON array is passed correctly to the adapter.

Comment: where is your json . post it

Comment: how do you pass the json to it? is it before defining the adapter or after it? 
do you call notifyDataSetChanged?

Comment: in order to create the adapter i must set it with the json. notifyDataSetChanged will help?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Question is not clear.What do you mean by "It doesn't show anything..". Please provide your JSON file as well as it might be going wrong there as well.